# Inserting variables into database?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to insert some post variables into a database and can't seem to get it to work. Here is my code at the moment.

```
 include('db_connect.php'); // = $connection

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
$row = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($row==0)
{
echo("email was not found");
mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO users (name, email, comfirmed) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$email."', 0)");

}
else
{
    echo("email was found");
}
```

I've tried several variations of the insert and can't get it to work. If I replace the variables with static values then it works fine and my database updates. I also realize there is issues with security at this point, but I want to focus of getting the insert to work then go back and fix those.

Comment: Please specify `can't get it to work`. What error do you get?

Comment: Please do print_r($_POST); and make sure values are posting. correctly.. do it step by step.. You can solve it..:)

Comment: I'm not getting any type of error. The variable are posting correctly I believe as I added a few dummy accounts and it will do the else statement if I give it an email already in the database.

Comment: What statement block doesn't it execute? if block or else block?

Comment: are you printing mysqli error??? using echo mysqli_error();

Comment: it executes both echo statements according to the what email was put it in. If the email is already in the data base it will echo "email was found" if not then it echos back "email was not found". I also tested this using name and it worked as well so the variables are posting correctly to be used in the select statement and the corresponding blocks are executing as well.

Comment: Ok.. then echo mysqli_error();... What error you getting..? Also check your database structure..

Answer (score 0):

There are many faults in your code. Most important ones are

- this code doesn't have any error reporting
- it doesn't format variables properly
- it is using mysqli

At the very least it have to be

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include('db_connect.php'); // as shown in http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info

$sql = "SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE email=?";
$stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute(array($_POST['email']));

if ($stm->fetchColumn()) {

    echo("email was not found");
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, email, comfirmed) VALUES (?, ?, 0)");
    $stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stm->execute(array($_POST['name'],$_POST['email']));

} else {
    echo("email was found");
}
```

or, if email has unique index on it ( as it have to be) you can make it in a single query

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include('db_connect.php'); // as shown in http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info

$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO users (name, email, comfirmed) VALUES (?, ?, 0)");
$stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute(array($_POST['name'],$_POST['email']));

if ($stm->rowCount()) {
    echo("email was not found");
} else {
    echo("email was found");
}
```